# I cannot save data from angular to backend laravel database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am passing form input from angular to laravel view api. But data cannot be saved in the database. I am getting the following error messages in the console:

```
error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=app%20in%20apps&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:292:254
    at http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:137:302
    at m.$digest (http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:399)
    at m.$apply (http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:341)
    at g (http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:94:139)
    at t (http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:98:260)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (http://localhost/myapp/public/app/lib/angular-1.5.0/angular.min.js:99:297)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13236
apps.js:28 0
http://localhost/myapp/public/api/apps Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
I also get laravel errors:
                            <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Illuminate\Database\QueryException">QueryException</abbr> in <a title="C:\xampp\htdocs\dukamart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php line 651" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Connection.php line 651</a>:</span>
span class="exception_message">SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column associated with input values.
```

I have checked my laravel controller seem to be fine. I am posting data from a popup form.

**employeeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Employee;

class Employees extends Controller
{
    //
     public function index($id = null) {
        if ($id == null) {
            return Employee::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        } else {
            return $this->show($id);
        }
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $employee = new Employee;

        $employee->name = $request->input('name');
        $employee->email = $request->input('email');
        $employee->contact_number = $request->input('contact_number');
        $employee->position = $request->input('position');
        $employee->save();

        return 'Employee record successfully created with id ' . $employee->id;
    }
```

**//My angular controller**

```
app.controller('employeesController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {
    //retrieve employees listing from API
    $http.get(API_URL + "employees")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.employees = response;
            });

    //show modal form
    $scope.toggle = function(modalstate, id) {
        $scope.modalstate = modalstate;

        switch (modalstate) {
            case 'add':
                $scope.form_title = "Add New Employee";
                break;
            case 'edit':
                $scope.form_title = "Employee Detail";
                $scope.id = id;
                $http.get(API_URL + 'employees/' + id)
                        .success(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            $scope.employee = response;
                        });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        console.log(id);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    //save new record / update existing record
    $scope.save = function(modalstate, id) {
        var url = API_URL + "employees";

        //append Employee id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
        if (modalstate === 'edit'){
            url += "/" + id;
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param($scope.employee),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            location.reload();
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
        });
    }

    //delete record
    $scope.confirmDelete = function(id) {
        var isConfirmDelete = confirm('Are you sure you want this record?');
        if (isConfirmDelete) {
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: API_URL + 'employees/' + id
            }).
                    success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        location.reload();
                    }).
                    error(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('Unable to delete');
                    });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

When I click to save the data, I am getting an error message I had setup in employeeController.js controller

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param($scope.hotel),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            location.reload();
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
        });
    }
```

This my app.js

```
var app = angular.module(employees, [])
        .constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost/myapp/public/api/');
```

My routes.php

```
Route::get('/api/v1/employees/{id?}', 'Employees@index');
Route::post('/api/v1/employees', 'Employees@store');
Route::post('/api/v1/employees/{id}', 'Employees@update');
Route::post('/api/v1/employees/update/{id}',['as'=>'update','uses'=> 'Employees@update']);
Route::delete('/api/v1/employees/{id}', 'Employees@destroy');
```

What could be the cause of this? Please help. I have tried to solve this for 3 days without success.

My View in resources/views/employees/employee.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="employeeRecords">
    <head>
        <title>Laravel 5 AngularJS CRUD Example</title>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="<?= asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Employees Database</h2>
        <div  ng-controller="employeesController">

            <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Contact No</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th><button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="toggle('add', 0)">Add New Employee</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                        <td>{{  employee.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.contact_number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ employee.position }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-detail" ng-click="toggle('edit', employee.id)">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete" ng-click="confirmDelete(employee.id)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- End of Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <!-- Modal (Pop up when detail button clicked) -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{form_title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form name="frmEmployees" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Fullname" value="{{name}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.name" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.name.$invalid && frmEmployees.name.$touched">Name field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{email}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.email" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.email.$invalid && frmEmployees.email.$touched">Valid Email field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" value="{{contact_number}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.contact_number" ng-required="true">
                                    <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.contact_number.$invalid && frmEmployees.contact_number.$touched">Contact number field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Position</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Position" value="{{position}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.position" ng-required="true">
                                    <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.position.$invalid && frmEmployees.position.$touched">Position field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" ng-click="save(modalstate, id)" ng-disabled="frmEmployees.$invalid">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Load Javascript Libraries (AngularJS, JQuery, Bootstrap) -->
        <script src="<?= asset('app/lib/angular/angular.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Application Scripts -->
        <script src="<?= asset('app/app.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('app/controllers/employees.js') ?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to post data using postman. it will work or not please check

Comment: I am getting similar internal error exception in postman on post request. Something should wrong somewhere. Kindly I need some help.

Comment: from above error it is like you are storing wrong value in database which are not follow database constraint

Comment: You are getting an ng-repeat error. The database issue is most likely a red herring. Can you please post the template code that contains the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

sound like your key is being duplicate in ng-repeat. Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: app in apps, Duplicate key: string:<, Duplicate value: <

this issue happens once

**Invalid:** 
ng-repeat="value in [4, 4]"

**valid**
ng-repeat="value in [4, 4] track by $index"

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.js` file.

Change the first line to:

```
var app = angular.module('employees', ['ngRoute'])
```